# What may the impact for executing create timeseries statement before insert statement in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I found that I can also execute the `insert` statement directly without executing `create timeseries` statement in Apache IoTDB. I checked the official guide, and seems like `create timeseries` should be executed before `insert` statement. I wonder if this order makes any difference in IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing ·insert· command in Apache IoTDB, it will do type inference and give the default encoding type. `Create timeseries`, however, can specify the encoding type, which can save some storage space in some data scenarios. Therefore, that's why the official guide recommended to execute `insert` command before `create timeseries` command.